# Oracle 12c Installation in Windows 7 error INS-30131

Tags: oracle, installation

I am trying to install Oracle 12c in a Windows 7 x64 computer and after a while I get this error:

```
SEVERE: [FATAL] [INS-30131] Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed.
   CAUSE: Failed to access the temporary location.
   ACTION: Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.
*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:*
- Framework setup check failed on all the nodes
- Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
- Action: User Action Not Available
Summary of the failed nodes
maddy-pc
- Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "XXXXXX"
- Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
- Action: User Action Not Available
```

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to install it without admin privileges.

Comment: Nope :) I am dumb but not THAT dumb.

Comment: In my case there was no C$ share. I shared with admin only permissions and did the trick.

Comment: I've too low reputation to answer, so as comment... For me the culprit was non-US-ASCII character in my user name (`Én`). First I've set `TEMP` and `TMP` to an accent-free path. But the installer creates folders inside `%TEMP%` like `CVU_12.1.0.1.0_Én` and `hsperfdata_Én`, and later it tries to access them with corrupted names, so it still fails. So when the error dialog popped up, I created links with the corrupted names (as `mklink /J CVU_12.1.0.1.0_Ă‰n CVU_12.1.0.1.0_Én` and `mklink /J CVU_12.1.0.1.0_En CVU_12.1.0.1.0_Én`, etc.), then retried by pressing "Next" again, and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. For reasons I don't understand Oracle needs access to the file system through the administrative network share (i.e. \computer\c$) and I had disabled it.

Things to check to solve this issue:

1. [Remove your computer from workgroups.](http://www.ehow.com/how_5125434_remove-computer-workgroup.html)
2. Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` `DWORD` value `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` to 1
3. Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters` `DWORD` value `AutoShareWks` to 1

Answer (score 5):

I finally got the answer for this error, this was because of the machine name being big. While setting up a new machine we should ensure that the machine name is not bigger then the bios name. which is 15 chars. This will definitely work.

Comment: One of my colleagues had this problem. As Incredible as it might seem, his PC name had 16 characters. After changing to less than 15, the installer worked!

Comment: This was the problem in my case. Renamed the machine, installation succeeded. Thank you!

Comment: In my case my Computer name is 14 char, but it has 2 chars `-`  in it (`XXX-XXXX-0000`). I change it to 9 chars with only 1 char `-`  (`XXXX-0000`)and restart, run setup again. Work like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue and failed even after trying many solutions.

Finally, I end up doing the following which might help some one but strongly advise you not to do this production environments.

Following Workaround is available to install database/client software if administrative shares is not enabled  :

```
 For client installs, run the installer with following arguments:
```

setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"

```
 For server installs, run the installer with following arguments:
```

setup.exe -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from Y.Ecarri above,

- Ensure the Server service is started. Go to run box and
  type services.msc. This should bring up the Services console.
- Type `\\<your-computer-name>` in the run box and check if you're able to
  see the shared folders.